# prettifying a part of the html doc using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an html doc which I would like to extract tables from, and prettify the tables. What I have so far is:

```
with open('html.txt','r') as file1:
    read_f=file1.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(read_f)

the_soup=soup.findAll('table', {'id': 'table_id'})
with open('prettified.txt','w') as f2:
    f2.write(the_soup.prettify())
```

But I am getting an error prettify is no an attribute.

Comment: Are there multiple `'table_id'`?

Comment: or it should be class. I was, however, reading of messy html tables with the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.findAll` will return a list of all table elements. You should iterate through this list and print the prettified version of each matched table:

```
with open('prettified.txt','w') as f2:
    for table in the_soup:
        f2.write(table.prettify())
```

Comment: Oh, that's where I was getting stuck. Thank you!